# Is a PGP revocation certificate sensitive?

Tags: pgp, smartcard, certificate-revocation

In relation to an openpgp key on a smartcard:

Besides revoking the key, is there anything else it can be (ab)used for? Can I just ensure it's reliably stored but not worry about it's confidentiality?

Comment: I'd still like to know the answer, preferably with an explanation of how a revocation cert. is generated. I've decided to store it when my secure offsite backups. If I had to guess a revocation certificate is "I declare <publickey> revoked LET IT BE KNOWN! - Signed by <privatekey>" but I'd really like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What a Revocation Certificate is About

Worst case in losing access to an OpenPGP key is that it probably is published on the key servers, and you have no chance in marking it as invalid any more, it will stay there forever, telling everybody "hey, that's my key, use it".

A **revocation certificate enables you to revoke your OpenPGP key if you lost access** to your private key by publishing it on the key servers.

> Besides revoking the key, is there anything else it can be (ab)used for? Can I just ensure it's reliably stored but not worry about it's confidentiality?

Whoever has access to it, can revoke your OpenPGP key. This cannot be undone once published. Using the revocation certificate, no further access can be obtained: it does not included the private key.

> If I had to guess a revocation certificate is "I declare  revoked LET IT BE KNOWN! - Signed by " but I'd really like to know.

In the end, that's exactly what it is. A revocation certificate is a special kind of signature on your OpenPGP key having some "revoke" bit set.

### How to Create a Revocation Certificate

A revocation certificate can be created by using `gpg --gen-revoke`. From `man gpg`:

```
   --gen-revoke name
          Generate a revocation certificate for the complete key.  To
          revoke a subkey or a signature, use the --edit command.
```

I recommend to store it both digitally in a safe place, but also print it (`qrencode` for encoding the ASCII-armored revocation certificate can do a great job here if you don't want to use OCR) and deposit it with somebody you know very well and trust.

Remember, even if you break up with that person, all he can do is revoking your key, not getting access to it. As you can add a description, you can even know which certificate was used for revoking your key and let the person know that to deter him.